# send() or sendAsync() while using Web3j to call functions

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

I built a java web application which connects using Web3j with my smart contract deployed on Ropsten Network.

My web application provides a control panel to allow the user to send transactions to the smart contract. Sometimes the user can send more than 5 calls at the same time. (actually much more than 5 :) )

I have a java class wrapper of my smart contract to call the functions of it.

> The question is: What I have to use, send() or sendAsync? How to
>   manage() I tried to use send() and sendAync().get() and I got the same
>   result.

```
TransactionReceipt receipt = myContract.callFunction1(...)         
).sendAsync().get();
```

What I get with this code is a long wait to complete the call and get the transaction receipt.... Is there another way to do this?

I know this could involve promises but I am not familiar with them. Could someone provide some code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can send and confirm transaction without waiting using CompletableFuture and callback function.
 rc-> Instance that calls contract function through remote call.

```
CompletableFuture<TransactionReceipt> transactionReceiptCompletableFuture = rc.sendAsync();

transactionReceiptCompletableFuture.thenAccept(transactionReceipt -> {

   // then accept gets transaction receipt only if the transaction is successful

 }).exceptionally(transactionReceipt  -> {
    return null;
 });
```

Comment: While implementing this and start debugging, it always jumps over the `thenAccept` and my IDE is telling me that CompletableFuture is not completed which ends in an Exception. Maybe I misunderstood the concept. Can someone give some further explanation with maybe some deeper/more code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

If the long wait is the problem, then you can create a thread. Then the request will get sent and you can go can continue execution without stalling out your program. See this example:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        final Web3j client = Web3j.build(
            new HttpService(RPC_NODE_URL_WITH_API_KEY)
        );
        Credentials metamaskCredentials = Credentials.create(WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY);
        ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider = new DefaultGasProvider();
        YourContractWrapper fpl = YourContractWrapper.load(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, client, metamaskCredentials, contractGasProvider);
        try {
          fpl.update(label, fingerprint).sendAsync().get(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch(TimeoutException e) {
          System.out.println("Timed out");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    });
    thread.start();
```